# Calculate max chat session concurrency in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concurrency, timestamp

I want to calculate the maximum number of chats and the number of customer service agents that are taking place at the same time. I have a table in which each row is a unique chat session. The following relevant columns are available:

- `chatsessionID` (count distinct gives the number of chats)
- `agentID`
- `sessionstart` (timestamp YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS)
- `sessionend` (timestamp YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS)

I tried the following query based on the `sessionstart` timestamps only. It produced the results I expected, but not what I needed:

```
SELECT
sessionstart,
COUNT(DISTINCT chatsessionID) AS Chats,
COUNT(DISTINCT agentID) AS Agents,
FROM source
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

This produced the number of chats and agents that **started** at a given `sessionstart` timestamp. It doesn't say how many chats and agents were active/being handled/handling a `chatsession` at a given timestamp. I'm looking for a way to enrich this insight so, I know how many chats and agents were active simultaneously.

Assume the data set has 5 chats in total. 3 chats started at 13:00, and 2 started at 12:55, ended at 13:05. Currently in my query above, the timestamp 13:00 returns 3 chats. But I need it to return 5, because 3 started at 13:00 and 2 were active at 13:00, because those two started before 13:00 and ended after 13:00.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are looking for how many other concurrent chats that is being handled by the same `agentID` for each `chatsessionID`, a left join to the same table on the same agent should be sufficient to achieve this:

```
SELECT
  a.agentID,
  a.chatsessionID, 
  a.sessionstart,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.chatsessionID) AS TotalConcurrentChats
FROM source a
LEFT JOIN source b
ON a.agentID = b.agentID
AND b.seasonstart >= a.seasonstart 
AND b.seasonend <= a.seasonend
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

But if you are looking for how many agents that is handling the same `chatsessionID`, a simple grouping should get this:

```
SELECT
    chatsessionID,
    MIN(sessionstart) sessionstart,
    MAX(sessionend) sessionend,
    COUNT(DISTINCT agentID) AS Agents
FROM source 
GROUP BY 1
```

UPDATE:

to get the total all active chats and agents given a specific time:

```
WITH time_dimension AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT sessionstart as seasontime
    FROM source
)  

SELECT
  a.seasontime,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.chatsessionID) AS Chats,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.agentID) AS Agents
FROM time_dimension a
LEFT JOIN source b
ON a.seasontime >= b.sessionstart
AND a.seasontime <= b.sessionend
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Let me know if I understood the question correctly or if you are looking for something else. An example of data; the source and what to expect to see would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but no that's not what I need. So in my example query, I stated that it produced results that gave me the number of chats and agents that started at a given timestamp. But, I need to see for that timestamp how many chats started AND how many chats were already active. Assume 3 chats started at 13:00, and 2 started at 12:55, ended at 13:05. Currently in my query, the timestamp 13:00 returns 3 chats. But I need it to return 5, because 3 started at 13:00 and 2 were active at 13:00. Is this maybe more clear?

Comment: I updated my answer. hope it helps.